# In Python is there a way to create data frames from a loop and use the number in the data frame name?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There are 48 files that I am looking to read in from GitHub into Python and am looking to use a loop to do this. Is there a way to name the dataframe using the number from loop?

```
number = 1  

while number < 48 :  
    gameweek[number] = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vaastav/Fantasy-Premier-League/master/data/2019-20/gws/gw"+str(number)+".csv")

    number = number+1
```

Open to any suggestions on how best to do this.

Comment: Er, what's the issue with the code you posted?

Comment: The only problem is that `gameweek[number]` is uninitialized variable, so initialize `gameweek` to an empty list `[]` (or empty dict `{}') before you use it. This has nothing to do with pandas or dataframes per se.

Comment: Why not have one single dataframe and another column holding the gameweek?

Comment: @vishnudev this is a good option! Will look into this if I can't get the separate data frames working.

Comment: @karl_knetchel it wasn't allowing me to have a separate data frame for each gameweek which is what I was trying I achieve. It was suggested that I create a dictionary key for each game week - which works! Although vishnudev did call out this may not be memory efficient when working with larger datasets.

Comment: @jpizz_888 Solution to process large datasets is to break gameweeks into chunks based on your requirements. If you need all the gameweek for processing, then you obviously will be needing a capable system or cloud infra. You could also use a distributed processing system like `dask` which is quite similar to pandas in terms of structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
number = 1  
gameweek = {}
while number < 48 :  
    gameweek['gw_' + str(number)] = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vaastav/Fantasy-Premier-League/master/data/2019-20/gws/gw"+str(number)+".csv")

    number += 1
```

Comment: I'm glad, I was helpful. Another tip `exec` is a in-built function, using which you can avoid using dictionary as well

Answer (score 1):

Your code it's good for what you're trying to do, you just need to **initialize** your `gameweek` structure to a dictionary, so you just need to add *before your while loop* the following line: `gameweek = {}`

Comment: This solution of using a dict for small data sets is good. but for larger datasets, it will just bloat up memory.

Comment: HI @Vishnudev I know, especially if you want to get 48 pages full of data, I think that the best alternative might be saving every page on a different txt file. What do you think?

Comment: How would that help? It would be the same. Reading from local vs remote doesn't help memory @Giovanni.

Comment: @giovanni thank you, you and Ajay A had the same idea and this works.

Comment: @vishnudev thankfully this is only using small amounts of data - 528rows and 32columns. I am really interested in knowing your views on what the best solution would be for larger datasets